# Why can't indirect super interface methods be called with super?

Tags: java, oop, jvm, invoke, super

Consider the following example (in a custom JVM language):

```
interface A { void foo() = println "A0" }
interface B extends A { override void foo() = println "A" }
interface C { void foo() = println "B" }

class D implements B, C
{
    override void foo() = super[A].foo // A.super.foo
}
```

This would have been rejected by the java compiler, because `A` is not a direct supertype of `D`. Since my programming language currently doesn't catch this error, I managed to get a JVM verification error:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: Bad invokespecial instruction: interface method reference is in an indirect superinterface.
Exception Details:
  Location:
    dyvil/test/Main$C.foo()V @1: invokespecial
  Reason:
    Error exists in the bytecode
  Bytecode:
    0000000: 2ab7 0015 b1
```

Why is this a problem for the JVM? I always though `invokespecial` was some way of saying 'invoke this instance method, but don't do dynamic dispatch'? Is the problem related to the `SUPER` access flag in the class file? And finally, is there a workaround?

Comment: To me this looks like its (intentionally) violating inheritance; effectively bypassing explicitly inherited code. No idea if the VM allows this by any means; my guess is no. You could emulate it by generating two versions of each interface method (normal one following java inheritance rules, and a copy that can be called explicitly; possibly by naming convention e.g. A_foo()). Your compiler would then need to substitute the alternate method name when bypassing inheritance. Not elegant but java already does something similar to allow inner classes access private enclosing class members.

Comment: I have thought about that already, and I believe Scala does this to make my example possible. However, this only works if `A` is available in Source, it wouldn't work for something like `Collection -> List -> D` when calling a default method from `Collection`.